# WCF: When the client timeout is shorter than the service timeout

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout

I have an question.
I wrote a WCF in my server and got a problem about timeout.
Father, I wrote a client to test my service.

Then, I assumed that I didn't know how long is the client's timeout, so I set my service timeout as 300(s).But actually, my client's timeout is 5(s).

So, when I ran my client, it got the timeout exception like "The operation has timed out".
Can I raise an exception when the client disconnects in my service?

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It's because that the client times out before the server responses. I want to prevent this situation by knowing when the client tries to disconnect.

Comment: Generally speaking, unless it's duplex, I don't think a service would need to be concerned about whether the client is still connected or not.  Is this a business requirement or some other reason you're trying to do this?